# Why is the size of embeded Presentations in Google Sites restricted?

Tags: google-sites

When I embed a Google Presentation into my Google site, the maximum size offered is "Large (700px)".

I would like to use the entire width of the page. Why is this limited and/or is there a way to overcome this restriction?

Comment: I believe the user has the option to go "full screen" if they want to - is that good enough?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to overcome it, but there is a fullscreen button on the slides.

Comment: I am aware about the full screen button and I have given a hint to the web site visitors in the first page of my online Manual. However, this is not a true solution. I would like to control  the web site appearance in this respect. I hope Google can improve it one day. On the other hand: Thanks for your Input and the hint that this cannot be overcome currently. It is a help since it stops me from looking for a solution which obviously does not exist.